# Can I manipulate an observable with multiple events from another observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's say I have an array of validation messages that map to input fields. Let's assume that we get these validation messages from a server.

I also have a stream of change events that map to input fields.

Whenever I get a change event for a given field I want to

1. See if there's a corresponding validation message for that field
2. Remove the validation message

Here's an example which hopefully illustrates why the usual suspects (combineLatest, withLatestFrom) don't get me over the line.

[image: validating filtering stream]

The issue with `combineLatest` is: The 4th change event will filter the 2nd validation array.

The issue with `withLatestFrom` is: The third change event will undo the work of the second change event.

Does anyone have any tips? Am I barking up the wrong tree? Have I over simplified the problem? Is there an RxJS method that's perfect for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted the above jsfiddle to show the solution I came up with.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hellosmithy/7kcoud2c/2/

Essentially this version uses `Rx.Observable.window` to chunk up the `changeEvents$` stream based on new events coming from the `validation$` stream.

```
var filteredValidation$ = validation$
    .merge(
        changeEvent$
        .window(validation$)
        .flatMapLatest(changeWindow => {
            return changeWindow.scan((acc, next) => acc.add(next), new Set());
        )
        .withLatestFrom(validation$, (filterSet, errs) => {
            return errs.filter(err => !filterSet.has(err.key));
        })
    )
    .distinctUntilChanged()
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you have a validation message, it seems you are starting anew the processing of the change events. In that case, you could try something like :

```
filteredValidation$ = validation$.flatMapLatest(function ( aObjs ) {
  return changeEvent$.scan(function ( acc, changeEvent ) {
    return isIn(changeEvent, acc) ? removeChangeEvent(changeEvent, acc) : acc;
  }, aObjs);
});
```

The `isIn` and `removeChangeEvent` you have to write according to the particular shape of `change_event` but that's pretty easy.

- every validation message will start a new stream
- that stream will have a state which is represented by the accumulator `acc` in the `scan` function, and that state itself is the latest filtered validation object.

I haven't tested, but hopefully it works.

BTW : I LOVE YOUR CHART, it is a perfect illustration of the processing you want to achieve.

Comment: Glad you like the chart. This solution results in the same scenario as combineLatest - whereby the 4th change event will filter the second validation array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer with a different technique. The idea is similar (using `scan` to remember previous value, but we make the current value from a reducing function which depends on the source emitting a value).

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/guc1tm4m/1

```
var ta_validation = document.getElementById('ta_validation');
var ta_change = document.getElementById('ta_change');
var ta_result = document.getElementById('ta_result');

function emits ( who, who_ ) {return function ( x ) {
 who.innerHTML = [who.innerHTML, who_ + " emits " + JSON.stringify(x)].join("\n");
};}

function isIn (changeEvent, prev){
  return !!prev[0][changeEvent];
}

function removeChangeEvent(changeEvent, prev) {
delete prev[0][changeEvent];
  return prev;
}

 var validation$ = Rx.Observable
 .fromEvent(document.getElementById('validation'), 'click')
 .map(function(_, index){
   var values=[
     [{a:'req', b:'req', c:'req'}],
           [{d:'req', e:'req'}],
           [{x:'req', y:'req', z:'req'}]
   ];
   return values[index % values.length];
   })
 .do(emits(ta_validation, 'validation'))
 .share();

var changeEvent$ = Rx.Observable
 .fromEvent(document.getElementById('change'), 'click')
 .map(function(_, index){
   console.log('ssds', index)
   var values=['x', 'a', 'b', 'z'];
   return values[index % values.length];
   })
 .do(emits(ta_change, 'change'))
 .share();

var filteredValidation$ = Rx.Observable
  .merge(validation$.map(function (x) {return function (  ) {return x;}}),
         changeEvent$.map(function ( changeEvent ) {
           return function ( prev ) {
             return isIn(changeEvent, prev) ? removeChangeEvent(changeEvent, prev) : prev;
           };
         }))
  .scan(function ( prev, f ) {
          return f(prev);
        }, {})
  .do(emits(ta_result, 'result'));

validation$.subscribe(function(){    });
changeEvent$.subscribe(function(){    });
filteredValidation$.subscribe(function(){    });
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I have a couple of questions though. This looks like you're mutating the validations stream - and is that considered idiomatic/good practice. It "feels" wrong to me but I'm new to Rx so what do I know?

Secondly - I'm not sure what's happening in in the `filteredValidations.merge(validations$.map(...))` line. You're returning a function that returns the value. Can you explain why you're doing that?

Third and least salient point - Suffixing streams with a $.... I like that, but can't decide wether I'll adopt that or not. Is that a commonly used convention?

Comment: 1. suffixing with $: don't remember where I saw this convention, but I loved it at first sight. I would not say it is commonly used. After all, reactive programming is not in the mainstream yet, so conventions are still up for the taking. But I prefer it to `obsName`, or `nameObs`, and just `name`.

Comment: 2. Stream mutation : No, I am not mutating the stream. Streams in Rx are mostly immutable. But I do transform that stream of validation objects into a stream of reducing functions. Those functions represent the operation to perform on the latest filtered validation object. So they take that latest validation object and return a new one. The latest validation object is available as the `prev` parameter in the `scan` function. Yes it is a little bit harder to reason with higher order functions, agreed. The previous solution with `flatMapLatest` is for sure simpler to understand.